# Auto Merge Editing in Workspace option shelf is gone?

Tags: modeling

[image]I just downloaded a new copy of Blender 2.8 and I can't find the Mesh Option Menu that had Auto Merge Editing. Mesh Option Menu seemed to be contained in a shelf that changed with each Workspace.  This shelf was between the Workspace tabs and the Header of the 3D Viewport Editor. It's probably simple......

Answer (score 6):

you can find this options in Active Tool and Workspace settings...
[image]

and another option is..
you can right click on any icon on header and in header menu you can find **Show Tool Settings**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As of 5/13/2019. Automerge Editing has been moved to the properties panel where you entered numerical input for Transform, View 3D Cursor, and Annotation. Just use hotkey N to toggle the new vertical menu bar. It's no longer under the Workspace Tabs in Mesh Options or in Active Tool or Workspace Settings.
[image]